# how to get assign values to check box in grid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i want to know status is active or not in check box. how to bind check box with database data. while editing im lossing previous data. data is not showing in check box

code behind updating event

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeadsAccess", ChkLeads.Checked);
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Leads">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkLeads" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

db column- [Leads]

Comment: Provide your code of initializing the grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkLeads" runat="server" 
            Checked='<%#bool.Parse(Eval("columnName").ToString())%>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..
you can bind the db value like this..

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkLeads" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("LeadsAccess"))%>'/>
```